# Production Google Marketplace app suddenly rejected without reason

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

My Google Marketplace app, a spreadsheets script, has been available in production and running for years now. It has been installed thousands of times. This past week the app was suddenly delisted which immediately broke it for hundreds of users. In the Marketplace SDK screen it says it was "Rejected", but I see no way to find the reason for the rejection.

Earlier in the last several months I got notice that the app would be removed if I didn't add a Privacy policy link, supposedly a new Marketplace requirement. I added the link a week before the required date and it was visible in the public Marketplace listing. I'm not sure how to tell if the contents of the privacy policy were unacceptable or if an automated system didn't recheck the updated privacy policy link status of the entry.

I don't have paid support because this is a free app that I publish on my own free time. I don't see a way to escalate this or to understand why an app was rejected suddenly after multiple years.

Comment: Hi Mike, is your app still rejected? If so try sending it for review again.
Can you tell me what the app id is (the number at the end of the URL), please?

Comment: For the Google Workspace Marketplace [app review process](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/about-app-review) an email is sent out containing a review document. The email used for this correspondence is the one provided by the [developer](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk#developer_links) in the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK under App Configuration -> Developer Email. The review process may take several days depending on how ready the app is.

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet Yes, thanks I got the notification that after resubmitting the application listing that it was reviewed and approved. The app ID is 328915503637, I would still love to know why it was suddenly rejected since it broke usage for many users. I would like to avoid breakage again in the future. Thanks!